# Cannot create air file because certification has expired

Tags: air

I followed [this tutorial](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ecc.html#ionCTAAnchor)  and got problem that certificate has expired.
I looked up in Air forum and found http://forums.adobe.com/message/2320586#2320586 which says the same problem that I got. Unfortunately, it has not been solved.

I am looking forward to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For development purposes, you can generate a basic, self-signed certificate with ADT or another certificate generation tool. You can also buy a commercial code-signing certificate from a commercial certificate authority such as VeriSign or Thawte.

If you need a self signed certificate, you can create one from Flex Builder or the SDK. If you are using a commercial certificate, you might have to pay to extend it.